ASP.NET Core model attribute [FromForm] not binding
Given the following two model classes:
public class TokenRequestModel
{
    [FromHeader(Name = HeaderName.RequestId)]
    public Guid? RequestId { get; set; }

    [FromHeader(Name = HeaderName.Authorization), Required, SwaggerParameter(DocConstants.Authorization, Required = true)]
    public required string Authorization { get; set; }

    [FromRoute(Name = RouteConstants.AuthorizationServerId)]
    public required string AuthorizationServerId { get; set; }
}

public class TokenRequest
{
    [FromForm(Name = "code")]
    public string? Code { get; set; }

    [FromForm(Name = "refresh_token")]
    public string? RefreshToken { get; set; }

    [FromForm(Name = "grant_type")]
    public required string GrantType { get; set; }

    [FromForm(Name = "redirect_uri")]
    public string? RedirectUri { get; set; }
}

If I pass TokenRequestModel & TokenRequest to the action method separately like this, it binds correctly:
public async Task<ActionResult<TokenResponse>> Exchange(
    TokenRequestModel tokenRequestModel,
    [FromForm]
    TokenRequest tokenRequest)        
{ }

But if I attempt to move TokenRequest into TokenRequestModel as a property like this, it does not bind.
public class TokenRequestModel
{
    [FromHeader(Name = HeaderName.RequestId)]
    public Guid? RequestId { get; set; }

    [FromHeader(Name = HeaderName.Authorization)]
    public required string Authorization { get; set; }

    [FromRoute(Name = RouteConstants.AuthorizationServerId)]
    public required string AuthorizationServerId { get; set; }

    [FromForm]
    public TokenRequest? TokenRequest { get; set; }
}

public async Task<ActionResult<TokenResponse>> Exchange(
    TokenRequestModel tokenRequestModel)        
{ }

I expected [FromForm] with url encoded form data to bind the form data to the TokenRequest property, but it does not. It is always null.
I have done this before with [FromBody] attribute and JSON data and it binds correctly.
Am I doing something wrong here? Or is this not possible?

Did you make changes to the TokenRequest class in the scenario where you added TokenRequest as a member of TokenRequestModel?

The new C# required modifier does not do what you think it does: it establishes a hard guarantee, enforced by the compiler, that the property-setter will be invoked before control returns to the caller of the ctor - this is entirely unrelated to the [RequiredAttribute] which you use for form validation. Given that a HTML <form> can be submitted with zero fields provided it means required cannot be used because you cannot use a compile-time guarantee as a runtime validation rule...

Also, it looks like you're trying to reimplement OAuth2's token-request/response flow - given it's a security aspect I recommend you use an existing library for this (like IdentityModel: https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityModel ) instead of trying to reinvent the wheel yourself.

@Kevin, no.  I did not make changes to the TokenRequest class between the two examples.

@Dai, how do you know what I think?    I know what required does and that modifier has nothing to do with my problem here.  As you can see, the TokenRequest property does not have this modifier.  Thanks, though.

@Dai, thanks for your suggestion to use IdentityModel, and I probably would if I could, but that is not possible here.  I am implementing a strict API specification and I need to have complete control over it.  Thanks anyway!

@MarkGood I made an assumption about your possible thought-process and I was wrong, fair enough; if I may explain: since C#11 came out I have seen a decent number of posts from people who did think the required modifier was a successor/replacement/equivalent-to (or just confused-with) the [Required] attribute - so I launched into my standard spiel.

@Dai, understood.   I removed several attributes for brevity, such as [Required] and [SwaggerParameter], and generally only leave required there so that I don't unintentionally forget to set these properties in my unit tests.  I want it to be explicit when I testing for null.  I have integration tests that detect when a [Required] property is missing.
